# Boiler Leak - Discharge Pipe - After Water Outage

Tags: water, boiler

Recently had our water supply off for about 24 hours due to a main break and didn't turn off the pipes to the house. I noticed today that the discharge pipe is slowly dripping. What is the cause/solution for this problem?

Comment: are you sure those two things are related? Correlation does not mean causation. Also, did you just happened to check the pipes because the power had been out, maybe it's been leaking for a while

Comment: that's a good point, i do check it fairly regularly (probably in the last month) and did not notice anything. i had a suspicion that the outage would not have had any clear type of impact like that, which it sounds is the case?

Comment: I suppose that anything that affects the water pressure could have caused it, or a cool/heat cycle that occurred because of the loss of power. Or maybe a spike in pressure from a restart? I'm thinking of things that could occur due to the power being out